# Exim4 error when adding router for autoreply "cannot be resolved at this time: error in redirect file: missing or malformed local part"

Tags: linux, debian, exim

I've installed and configured Exim4 on Debian9. Everything works fine until when I add a router/transport for autoreply.

I added those fields:

[Router section]

```
uservacation:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
  allow_filter
  hide_child_in_errmsg
  ignore_eacces
  ignore_enotdir
  reply_transport = vacation_reply
  no_verify
  require_files = $home/.vacation.msg
  file = $home/.vacation.msg
  unseen
```

[Transport section]

```
vacation_reply:
  driver = autoreply
```

When I add those in I then am unable to resolve the user that has the .vacation.msg in hos home folder and when executing "exim -bt user@domain.com" I get:

```
user@domain.com cannot be resolved at this time: error in redirect file: missing or malformed local part (expected word or "<") in "body text of file vacation.msg"
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: As the error is complaining about something in the body of the file vacation.msg, please edit your question to include the contents of that file. edit: scratch that; the `file = ` value sets a filter file to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The `file =` sets the file containing filtering rules, which are enabled by the `allow_filter` directive. You could move the `file =` line to the vacation_reply transport where it does configure what to send as a reply, but using a filter file offers more flexibility and is my preference.

That filter file should look similar to this:

```
# Exim filter

if personal
then vacation
    from "user@domain.com"
    subject "automatic reply: out of office"
    once .vacation.once
    once_repeat 5d
endif
```

`personal` checks whether the recipient's email address is in the headers (i.e. it's not a mailing list, for example).

`vacation` handles sending the reply message. The `once` file registers that a reply has been sent so that multiple messages aren't sent to the same address within 5 days as specified by the `once_repeat 5d` line.

One hint: don't specify `return message` or use the original subject as part of the vacation message subject, as that can be misused to distribute spam.